# Java SSLSocket for mmorpg game server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm writing a thread/connection mmorpg server in Java, and I was wondering, should I use the normal Socket class and add security to the connection by myself(exchanging keys with a certain handshake order?), or is it better to use SSLSocket class to connect the clients with the server all the time?
Are there any benchmarks or performance tests that show the performance of the SSLSocket class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most MMO Servers don't use SSLSockets, but for your case it would be advisable. You should do a Diffie-Hellman-Keyexchange over an SSL Connection and then encrypt all following packets symmetrically with Blowfish, for example.

Addendum:
I don't think it still holds that SSLSockets put much more load on a server. If the server is fairly recent, he should be able to cope with the little extra load of encryption. I know of StarCraft 2 that it encrypts the packets on it's own and uses UDP for that purpose. Also, WOW uses encryption on it's packets, to prevent altering of the data on their way and sniffing of player positions aso. Encryption is for every MMO a must, but how you implement it is up to you.

I point you to this thread, where this problem is discussed: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/589113-should-mmorpgs-use-encryption/

Also, there is a google book about this problem:
http://books.google.at/books?id=hiBFUv_FT0wC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks a lot! been looking for such a book for a while!

Comment: No problem. There are a lot of books out there about MMO design and stuff. Maybe, (I don't know where you live), if you visit the local technical university (computer science would be the right field), you can get a hold on some of these books, at the university library. Most universities also provide a shop, where you can buy or order most of them. Try it. (I study at the technical university of vienna, and had a look at the gaming section today, there are some that could be of use. Most other universities should have them too.)

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt an MMO server would have the extra bandwidth available to keep deciphering SSL packets. I would use SSL for the login and then downgrade to a regular socket.

Comment: Is there a direct way to downgrade to regular socket? Or should I reconnect the client with a handler or something like that?

Comment: Well, chances are you'll need a reconnect anyway. You're not planning on having the game server and login server on the same process anyway, are you? ... Are you...? Good, I didn't think you'd let yourself fall into THAT trap! :-) (Hint: doing that will cause massive scaling issues down the road, so don't fall into that trap.) Most of your data will probably be sent in UDP anyway so you'll have an extra socket anyway.

Comment: One last question, can you give me any good book name or link me to some good resource for this subject? I didn't seem to find much even though i searched for a long time :-(. And thanks for your answers :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. A lot of what I learned was through trial and error, and just conversations with some seasoned developers.